# an exercice for uniquesess solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i have this exercice
Let the problem $$y'=f(y) g(x) , y(x_0)=y_0$$
if $f(y_0)=0$ what are the conditions on $f$ for the probleme admits a unique solution
thank's

Comment: Use the Picard-Lindeloef's Theorem to give a sufficient condition...

Comment: $f(y)$ has to be Lipschetz continuous by Picard-Lindeloef's theorem.

Comment: We use Picard theorem to $f(y) g(x)$ not just to $f(y).$ or not?

Comment: @lili: Read the theorem carefully, if $y'=G(x,y)$, then we require $G$ to be Lipschitz continuous in $y$ and continuous in $x$.

Comment: ok! $f(y)$ must be lipschitz . But why lipschitz continuous? if $f$ is lipschiz, so she is continuous!

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$f(y)g(x)=h(x,y) $$

If both $h(x,y)$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}(x,y) $ are continuous over some rectangle $R$ then for $(x_{0},y_{0})\in R$ the solution exists and it is unique